# $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$

Tags: analytic-geometry

The equation $$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$ represents a pair of parallel lines. Prove that the equation of the line mid way between the two parallel lines us $hx+by+f=0$

My Attempt:

Let the lines be $lx+my+n_1=0$ and $lx+my+n_2=0$.
Then,
$$(lx+my+n_1)(lx+my+n_2)=0$$

Comparing the above equation with $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$, we get:
$l^2=a, m^2=b, lm=h, l(n_1+n_2)=2g, m(n_1+n_2)$

Also,

distance between the two parallel lines represented by the given equation is $d=2 \sqrt {\frac {g^2 -ac}{a(a+b)}}$

$d=2 \sqrt {\frac {g^2 -ac}{h^2 +a^2}}$?

Now, what should I do to complete the proof?

Comment: Your final equation should be $lx+my+\frac{n_1+n_2}{2} = 0$. Multiply this equation by $m$ and substitute the values as per the equations that you derived.

Comment: @expiTT, how do I get there? And what is the equation derived?

Comment: Use distance formula between two parallel lines and check that the parallel line (say $lx+my+n=0$) midway between the two parallel lines in your explanation must satisfy $|n_1-n|=|n-n_2|$. This will give you $n=\frac{n_1+n_2}{2}$.

Comment: Hint: you’ll need to multiply the equation $lx+my+(n_1+n_2)/2=0$ by some constant factor to get it into the desired form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarifing the last hint. The line mid is also parallel to the others lines, so it has the form:
$$lx+my+d=0\tag{1}$$
but it lies in the middle, so $(0,-n_1/m)$ at the first line and $(0,-n_2/m)$ at the second line are both at the same vertical line and then the middle point $(0, -(n_1+n_2)/2m)$ must belongs to the line (1). Thats why we must have $d=(n_1+n_2)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

The line mid way between parallel lines $lx+my+n_1=0$ and $lx+my+n_2=0$ is $$lx+my+\frac{n_1+n_2}{2}=0.$$

**Why?**

When considering parallel lines, the distance in any direction is enough to look for the mid line. You do not need to take the *perpendicular* one.

[image]

Thus, you can consider, for instance, the distance in the $y$-axis direction. Line $lx+my+n=0$ crosses the vertical axis at point $(0,−n/m)$. Of course, it is the same for $n_1$ and $n_2$.

So distances between any two of those points $(0,a)$ and $(0,b)$ is given by $|a-b|$. In particular, in the case of the parallel lines, the mid line needs to satisfy $|n_1-n|=|n-n_2|$.